# Randomly copy 50 musicfiles from folder with subdirs to another folder

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a folder structure that contains my music files in the formats `mp3` and `flac`
The folder structure looks like this:

```
S:\Music\
     |___\ABBA
     |___\...
     |___\ZZTop
```

I'm trying to create a Powershell script that selects **randomly** 50 files from the `Music` directory (including its subdirectories) and puts it in another folder.

I tried this script but it does not work.

```
$d = gci "S:\Music\*.mp3" | resolve-path  |  get-random -count 50
Copy-Item $d  -destination 'S:\Music\RandomFIles'
```

It throws this error: `Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.`

Comment: so ... have you tested the steps of your 1st line pipeline? at what stage do you NOT have any result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the need for `| Resolve-Path |`?
You need to append switch `-File` to Get-ChildItem so you are not retrieving DirectoryInfo objects together with FileInfo objects.

Then use the `.FullName` property on the `-Path` parameter (which is the first positional parameter that expects a string array)
See [Copy-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?#parameters)

Depending on how large the music collection is, this may take its time to complete

By using a destination folder INSIDE the folder you are recursively iterating for files, you may get exception:
*"Copy-Item : Cannot overwrite the item blah.mp3 with itself."*
so to avoid that, you will need to append `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the Copy-Item command.

Below copies both .MP3 and .FLAC files:

```
# loop through the music folders and search for the file patterns you need to copy
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'S:\Music' -File -Include '*.mp3', '*.flac' -Recurse | Get-Random -Count 50
Copy-Item -Path $files.FullName -Destination 'S:\Music\RandomFiles' -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

However, if you only want to copy say .MP3 files, then note that parameter `-Filter` works faster than `-Include` but..

- `-Filter`  allows only ONE file name pattern like '*.mp3'
- `-Include` allows for an array of name patterns, but can only be used if the path ends with `\*`, OR when the `-Recurse` switch is also used

```
# loop through the music folders and search for the single file pattern you need to copy
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'S:\Music' -File -Filter '*.mp3' -Recurse | Get-Random -Count 50
Copy-Item -Path $files.FullName -Destination 'S:\Music\RandomFiles' -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

In both cases, make sure the destination path exists.

---

**Edit**

As you have discovered, running the first code block several times, can leave you with a total number less than 50 items on each run.
This is because `Get-Random -Count 50` can return files that were already in the destination folder and the code above simply copies over them.
Also, for me it is not clear if `Get-Random -Count 50` itself does not return duplicates.. So far I haven't seen that, but it is possible that upon return the 50 items may not always be unique.

To overcome that, below makes sure every file copied is not already to be found in the destination folder and it will always return 50 files without duplicates.

**A warning though:**
When running over and over, you may end up with an endess loop if there are no more files in the source folder that haven't already been copied.

```
$sourceFolder = 'S:\Music'
$destination  = 'S:\Music\RandomFiles'  # this folder MUST already exist 

# first create a Hashtable with file already in the destination folder (Names only)
$existing = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination  -File -Filter '*.mp3' | ForEach-Object { $existing[$_.Name] = $true }

# next loop through the music folders and search for the single file pattern you need to copy
# if the destination folder is NOT in the sourcefolder, you can leave out the Where-Object clause
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File -Filter '*.mp3' -Recurse | Where-Object{ -not $_.DirectoryName.StartsWith($destination) }
# make sure you do not exceed the total number of files
$totalFiles = @($files).Count
$maxFiles = [math]::Min($totalFiles, 50)
# start a counted loop
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxFiles; $i++) {
    $rnd = Get-Random -Maximum $totalFiles                  # get a random array index from the complete $files collection
    if ($existing.ContainsKey($files[$rnd].Name)) { $i-- }  # file is already present; decrease the counter
    else {
        Write-Host "Copying file no. $($i + 1)/$maxFiles"
        $files[$rnd] | Copy-Item -Destination $destination  # copy the file
        $existing[$files[$rnd].Name] = $true                # and add its name to the Hashtable
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought the script selects 50 files and puts them in the folder after having selected them, so I didn't think about "recursive". I don't want to include the `flac` file they are to large and should not go into that selection. That's why I used `*.mp3`

Comment: Upon executing the script several times, I noticed it does not put 50 items into the folder destination. It is any number between 9 and 50. I've tested several times and it seems like with each execution the amount of copied items decreases.

Comment: @Phil Please see my edit

Comment: Yes, this script does exactly what I wanted it to. It became rather complicated compared to the initial one, and it seems to take its time. The first suggestion was very quick, under a second (not actually measured) But that's no problem since I don't have to run it often. I will kindly accept your answer.

Comment: By running it over and over, you mean consecutively? If I reboot the computer and run the script again, there's no file where already copied items are stored or if I empty them out of the destination folder, is there?

Comment: @Phil yes, that is what I meant. If you start with an empty destination folder then there is nothing to worry about. Only if you run it over and over again without ever emptying that folder, you will end up with a script that cannot find a new file to copy, because they are already all copied to the destination. You'd probably won't ever want to use it that way, but I just thought I'd mention it ;)